# ssh connection to ssh server working from within LAN but not from internet

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, port-forwarding

I installed the openssh server on my ubuntu server, which is behind a fritzbox router. The sshd_config is:

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
#PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
```

So I am perfectly able to connect to the server from within my lan, yet I want to connect from anywhere within the internet to my home server. So I used a dyndns server and it works well. From the anywhere I can run:

```
nc -z blabla.selfhost.co 22
Connection to blabla.selfhost.co port 22 [tcp/ssh] succeeded
```

Now here is the verbose output from the ssh command

```
ssh -vvv bla@blabla.selfhost.co

OpenSSH_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/BLA/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to blabla.selfhost.co port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/BLA/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/BLA/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/BLA/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/BLA/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/BLA/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/BLA/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/BLA/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/BLA/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/BLA/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/BLA/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug3: fd 5 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to blabla.selfhost.co:22 as 'bla'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/BLA/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/BLA/.ssh/known_hosts:18
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from blabla.selfhost.co
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 34
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<3072<8192) sent
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: bits set: 1569/3072
debug3: send packet: type 32
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 33
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:stKU5NgYR5Vs8jsCLIpvdy0cO6Wze5KY0sj0+2ng5WA
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/BLA/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/BLA/.ssh/known_hosts:18
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from blabla.selfhost.co
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/BLA/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/BLA/.ssh/known_hosts:18
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 83.169.40.234
debug1: Host 'blabla.selfhost.co' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/BLA/.ssh/known_hosts:18
debug2: bits set: 1548/3072
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug2: key: /Users/BLA/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f993c0017b0)
debug2: key: /Users/BLA/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /Users/BLA/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /Users/BLA/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0x0)
debug2: key: /Users/BLA/.ssh/id_xmss (0x0)
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:bITNYUVDZe1M0/0G8xHsrNbI+zPWO3A6NLzC6PSq7z8 /Users/BLA/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/BLA/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/BLA/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/BLA/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/BLA/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/BLA/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /Users/BLA/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/BLA/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /Users/BLA/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
bla@blabla.selfhost.co's password: 
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
Permission denied, please try again.
```

/var/log/auth.log shows no sign of any attempts, i opened the firewall as instructed. Where am I erring?

Comment: The fact that the ssh server identifies itself as OpenSSH version 5.3  makes me think that you are in fact ssh'ing into the router and not your Ubuntu machine. No fairly recent Ubuntu version has that old ssh version. Did you forward port 22 properly on your router to the Ubuntu machine?

Comment: A good guess! So if I run it on the server I get
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.10
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.10
Which diverges from the above. I THINK I port forwarded. Chose port 22 and the static IP of my server. I will reiterate that step.

Comment: I have a question. Shouldn't the ip I get with nslookup and my dyndns domain as answer and the public IP i get via different measures (whatsmyip.org) or something be the same IP? Because they are not.

Comment: Yes, dyndns should assign to your domain your public IP address, ie. the external address of your router - that's what you usually get via tools like whatsmyip.org. If dyndns assigns a different address to you, something's wrong. Try first ssh from Internet to your public IP address, without using a domain name. If you succeed, you at least know that you have forwarded the port correctly. Then you may try to find error in the DNS setup.

Comment: If the addresses are different, then it is possible that between your router and the Internet there's another router (for example your ISP's) that does another NAT. In that case you are out of luck, because that router won't forward connection to your router.

Comment: Hey Raj, thank you again for elaborating your perspective. A question: Could traceroute help me to answer that question you raised in your last post definitely, given I know the two different IPs?

Comment: Yes, I think traceroute could be helpful with that.

Comment: Dear Raj, the lead you provided was correct. It was an ISP and routing thing, i had to tunnel my to IPv6 using a virtual server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the fact that IPv4 had to be tunneled to IPv6. The solution I employed was:

1. Get a vServer for 1 euro a month (IP == vServerIP4)
2. Change standard port for ssh in /etc/ssh/sshd_config to 23 on my homeserver (IP == homeSeverIP6)
3. Open that port in the firewall and forward it on my router.
4. Run "6tunnel 23 homeSeverIP6 23" on the vServer
5. Connect via "ssh -p 23 Kai@vServerIP4" to my homeServer

Thanks @raj for the help!